# Reactive parallelization doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Using project Reactor 3.0.4.RELEASE. Conceptually, should be same in RxJava as well.

```
public Mono<Map<String, Boolean>> refreshPods(List<String> apps) {
    return pods(apps)
            .filter(this::isRunningAndNotThisApp)
            .groupBy(Item::getName)
            .flatMap(g -> g
                    .distinct(Item::getIp)
                    .collectList()
                    // TODO: This doesn't seem to be working as expected
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("par-grp"))
                    .flatMap(client::refreshPods))
            .flatMap(m -> Flux.fromIterable(m.entrySet()))
            .collectMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
}
```

The idea is to run `client.refreshPods` in a separate thread for each group.

**Edit**: I'd tried `publishOn` before posting this question and after the answers given here, but the output doesn't change.

Client:

```
public class MyServiceClientImpl implements MyServiceClient {
    private final RestOperations restOperations;
    private final ConfigRefreshProperties configRefreshProperties;

    public Mono<Map<String, Boolean>> refreshPods(List<Item> pods) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(pods)
                .zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(configRefreshProperties.getRefreshDelaySeconds())),
                        (x, delay) -> x)
                .flatMap(this::refreshWithRetry)
                .collectMap(Tuple2::getT1, Tuple2::getT2);
    }

    private Mono<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> refreshWithRetry(Item pod) {
        return Mono.<Boolean>create(emitter -> {
            try {
                log.info("Attempting to refresh pod: {}.", pod);
                ResponseEntity<String> tryRefresh = refresh(pod);

                if (!tryRefresh.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    log.error("Failed to refresh pod: {}.", pod);
                    emitter.success();
                } else {
                    log.info("Successfully refreshed pod: {}.", pod);
                    emitter.success(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.error(e);
            }
        })
                .map(b -> Tuples.of(pod.getIp(), b))
                .log(getClass().getName(), Level.FINE)
                .retryWhen(errors -> {
                    int maxRetries = configRefreshProperties.getMaxRetries();
                    return errors.zipWith(Flux.range(1, maxRetries + 1), (ex, i) -> Tuples.of(ex, i))
                            .flatMap(t -> {
                                Integer retryCount = t.getT2();
                                if (retryCount <= maxRetries && shouldRetry(t.getT1())) {
                                    int retryDelaySeconds = configRefreshProperties.getRetryDelaySeconds();
                                    long delay = (long) Math.pow(retryDelaySeconds, retryCount);
                                    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(delay));
                                }
                                log.error("Done retrying to refresh pod: {}.", pod);
                                return Mono.<Long>empty();
                            });
                });
    }

    private ResponseEntity<String> refresh(Item pod) {
        return restOperations.postForEntity(buildRefreshEndpoint(pod), null, String.class);
    }

    private String buildRefreshEndpoint(Item pod) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://{podIp}:{containerPort}/refresh")
                .buildAndExpand(pod.getIp(), pod.getPort())
                .toUriString();
    }

    private boolean shouldRetry(Throwable t) {
        boolean clientError = ThrowableAnalyzer.getFirstOfType(t, HttpClientErrorException.class)
                .map(HttpClientErrorException::getStatusCode)
                .filter(s -> s.is4xxClientError())
                .isPresent();

        boolean timeoutError = ThrowableAnalyzer.getFirstOfType(t, TimeoutException.class)
                .isPresent();

        return timeoutError || !clientError;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the log statement `Attempting to refresh pod` is printed on the same thread for every group. What am I missing here?

**Logs from test run**:

```
2017-02-07 10:g12:55.348  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Attempting to refresh pod: Item(name=news, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.357  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Successfully refreshed pod: Item(name=news, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.358  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Attempting to refresh pod: Item(name=parking, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.363  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Successfully refreshed pod: Item(name=parking, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.364  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Attempting to refresh pod: Item(name=localsearch, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.368  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Successfully refreshed pod: Item(name=localsearch, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.369  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Attempting to refresh pod: Item(name=auth, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.372  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Successfully refreshed pod: Item(name=auth, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.373  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Attempting to refresh pod: Item(name=log, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.377  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Successfully refreshed pod: Item(name=log, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.378  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Attempting to refresh pod: Item(name=fuel, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
2017-02-07 10:12:55.381  INFO 33905 --- [        timer-1] c.n.d.cloud.config.MyServiceClientImpl  : Successfully refreshed pod: Item(name=fuel, ip=127.0.0.1, port=8888, podPhase=Running).
```

Comment: you have a `log` in there, could you share its output? also can you confirm there can be several `Item` with the same `name` (ie grouping does actually produces groups with several elements)? Have you tried `publishOn` rather than `subscribeOn`, as you are only interested in executing the downstream in separate thread?

Comment: You need `publishOn` after the TODO line, not `subscribeOn`.

Comment: @akarnokd That's my understanding too as I want to emit on separate threads, doesn't work. See edit.

Comment: There was a bug that made `flatMap( -> observeOn(s).X )` not properly running on "s". I'm not sure which Reactor release contains the fix but for a quick workaround, the last operator inside the flatMap should be `hide()`: `flatMap( ->  observeOn().X().hide())`.

Comment: @akarnokd I assume you meant `publishOn` as there's no `observeOn` in reactor. But that doesn't work as well :(

Comment: Filed [#421](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/421)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer myself for completeness. With help from @simon-baslé and @akarnokd, I got it right. Both of the following work. See [reactor-core#421](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/421) for details.

**Solution 1**:

```
zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(groupMemberDelaySeconds)),
    (x, delay) -> x)
.publishOn(Schedulers.newParallel("par-grp"))
.flatMap(this:: refreshWithRetry)
```

**Solution 2**:

```
zipWith(Flux.intervalMillis(1000 * groupMemberDelaySeconds, Schedulers.newTimer("par-grp")),
    (x, delay) -> x)
.flatMap(this:: refreshWithRetry)
```

No `subscribeOn` or `publishOn` is necessary in the `refreshPods` method.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: As made more explicit thanks to your newly provided log, and as picked up by David in the issue you created, the root cause is that you use an `interval` here. This will switch context to the default `TimedScheduler` (which will be the same for all groups). That's why anything done before the call to `refreshPods` seems to be ignored (work is done on the interval thread), but publishOn/subscribeOn *after* the interval operator should work. In a nutshell **my advice of using `subscribeOn` directly after the `create` still stands**.

You trigger a blocking behavior (`refresh(pod)`) that you wrap as a `Mono` in `refreshWithRetry`.

Unless you have a strong need for being concurrency-agnostic at this level, I'd advise you to immediately chain your `subscribeOn` next to the `create`.

This way, no surprise when using that `Mono`: it respects the contract and doesn't block. Like this:

```
return Mono.<Boolean>create(emitter -> {
        //...
    })
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("par-grp"))
.map(b -> Tuples.of(pod.getIp(), b))
```

If you want the method to return a concurrency-agnostic publisher, then you'd need to put the `subscribeOn` closer to your blocking publisher, so you'd need to expand the `flatMap` lambda:

```
.flatMap(pods -> client.refreshPods(pods)
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("par-grp"))
)
```

Comment: Your 2nd solution doesn't work, see edit. If I'm not wrong, your first solution would run each item in the group on a separate thread, right? That's different from running each group on a separate thread but each item on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you put `publishOn` before `flatMap`. Methods combining observables like `flatMap` or `zip` do their own re-scheduling when working with async sources. `interval` is such an async source in your case. That is why you get all results on 'timer' thread.

1) Use `publishOn` *right before the operation you wish to go in parallel*. The operation itself should not involve re-scheduling. Eg. `map` is a good one, `flatMap` is bad.

2) Use another `publishOn` right after it to reschedule results. Otherwise subscriber's thread might interfere.

```
Flux.range(1, 100)
        .groupBy(i -> i % 5)
        .flatMap(group -> group
                .publishOn(Schedulers.newParallel("grp", 8))
                .map(v -> {
                    // processing here
                    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    logger.info("processing {} from {} on {}", v, group.key(), threadName);
                    return v;
                })
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
        )
        .subscribe(v -> logger.info("got {}", v));
```

In case you want to make sure all group's items run on the same thread see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41697348/697313

Comment: I'm not sure that the 2nd `publishOn` makes sense and it didn't work anyway.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Try my example - I've tested it on 3.0.4, and it works - then gradually build your code on top of it. Try with and without second `publishOn` and see.

Comment: Actually, I suggest you try the example in ticket [#421](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/421). The problem with your example is what I call the "hello world" syndrome; it only deals with a piece of the problem, and sometimes a piece doesn't fit the bigger puzzle. Just for kicks, I did run your code for the example in the ticket and and like I said before, it didn't work for my use case. Try for yourself and let me know.

Comment: Without understanding how "hello world" works, you can hardly build something bigger.

Comment: Let's not extend this conversation unless you'd like to suggest something that works for the question posted. Anything else is irrelevant.